# Docker XDebug install when no-PHP-based image

Tags: php, docker-compose, xdebug

I know how to setup XDebug in docker containers.
All Dockerfile samples based on PHP image (FROM php:something).
Unfortunately, our team Dockerfile based on Debian image (FROM debian:something).

Do the following in Dockerfile to install XDebug in container:

```
# Install PHP with extensions
RUN curl -sSLo /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    php8.3-cli php8.3-curl php8.3-fpm php8.3-intl php8.3-mbstring php8.3-xml php8.3-bcmath \
    php8.3-pgsql \
    php8.3-imagick php8.3-gd \
    php8.3-soap \
    php8.3-zip \
    php8.3-dev

# Case 1: PECL-based XDebug 3
RUN apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar && \
    php go-pear.phar && \
    rm go-pear.phar
RUN pecl install xdebug

# Case 2: XDebug 3 - compile from sources
#ENV XDEBUG_VERSION '3.3.1'
#RUN cd /tmp && \
#    git clone https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git && \
#    cd xdebug && \
#    phpize && \
#    ./configure --enable-xdebug && \
#    make && \
#    make install
```

Then copy php.ini changes for xdebug into container.

When docker compose build finished, I observe Debian filesystem inside container and see in `php --version` output - no XDebug extension + warning = XDebug extension file not found in both cases below:

1. Case 1 (PECL) - I see in quick messages during container build / up
   that pecl successfully installed xdebug. It's not true.
2. Case 2 (compile from sources). Again XDebug not installed. Trying to repeat step by step in container shell and found that phpize not found (((. Meantime php8.3-dev installed before.

How to install XDebug in container for Debian-based image?

**Update**: "XDebug not installed" - meant no xdebug.so at extension folder as it should be in the right case. My question is not about php.ini xdebug keys.

Comment: You need to show the output of all of this, when you build your image. FWIW, instead of installing pear yourself, you can also do `apt install php8.3-pear`.

Comment: This package doesn't exist, sorry